# Передача данных между потоками

Tags: python, многопоточность

Необходимо запустить бесконечный поток, который будет периодически вызывать callback функцию, которая меняет данные в главном потоке. Пытаюсь делать как указано ниже в примере.

В примере ожидается, что грустные смайлики через пару секунд сменятся на веселые. Но нет. Программа запускается, функция foo_callback вызывается (если в нее вставить print("bla bla") в терминал нормально выводит), однако, если пытаться поменять значение переменной status, то ничего не происходит. Скорее всего я плохо курил потоки, подскажите, как достичь такого эффекта. Пробовал использовать очередь, но там необходимо окончание потока, а мне надо в процессе работы бесконечного потока периодически скидывать информацию в главный поток.

В принципе желаемого эффекта можно достичь передавая данные через глобальную переменную, но, черт, это же глобальная переменная, наверняка есть красивый способ.

Пример:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def very_very_long_func(foo_callback):
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        foo_callback(":)")

status=":("

def it_callback(s):
    status=s

thrd = Thread(target = very_very_long_func, args= ( it_callback,))
thrd.start()

while thrd.is_alive():
    print(status)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать оператор `global`, чтобы сделать присвоение глобальной переменной вместо создания локальной копии внутри функции:

```
import time
from threading import Thread


def very_very_long_func(foo_callback):
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        foo_callback(":)")

status = ":("

def it_callback(s):
    global status
    status = s

thrd = Thread(target=very_very_long_func, args=(it_callback,))
thrd.start()

while thrd.is_alive():
    print(status)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

т.е. без `global status` у вас просто внутри `it_callback` будет создана переменная `status`, которая исчезнет после того как функция завершится.

Comment: Да, я использовал глобальную переменную, и в данном конкретном случае этого достаточно и работает, но хотелось бы что-то вроде callback. Например если писать таймер в отдельном потоке, то хотелось бы, чтобы он таким образом генерировал события. А с глобальной переменной придется непрерывно мониторить ее состояние.